# How to use Spring Web Services correctly after the contract is complete?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-ws

I'm modernizing something that was written in .NET 2.0 VB and bringing the code up to current Java 11 standards, while maintaining the contract of the web service.

I used the [Initializer](https://start.spring.io/) to create a Spring Boot 2.2.5 app with Spring Web Services and then used the [WS Reference Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/3.0.8.RELEASE/reference/), [Core Technologies](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html), and the [WS Getting Started Guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/). Now I have the contract, it hasn't changed in years and can't change yet, but I started the guide and cross referenced the WS Reference Doc all along the way and then ran the app.

Now my questions are:

1. The WS docs state that at some point you're going to be done and you should grab the wsdl from the browser and save it and change from **dynamic-wsdl** to **static-wsdl**. When this takes place where do the generated files get moved to? During dynamic development they stay out in the target folder and are put on the classpath and are never checked in to source control.
2. This I hope is not a deal breaker, but my schema has warts, after almost 20 years and I know that Spring has conventions it likes to use for the request and response messages. Is there any way to retrofit the bad schema so that Spring is happy? This would have to be done on a method by method approach since we wen't consistent in the beginning.

As a side note I have a Maven project setup on the side that I use to generate stub code from the wsdl with CXF and JAXB and can change almost every aspect of the generated code, like the request and response names, but that's after the fact. Can I bring these files into Spring?

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe very concise edits.

Comment: Just use JAXB to generate the model objects, then write the proper `@Endpoint` methods. Or use something else like CXF to generate the web service stubs as well.